# Continuity for $f(x)=\begin{cases} x, \text{when $x\leqslant0$} \\ \frac{1}{x-1}, \text{when $x>1$} \end{cases}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

> Let $f:(-\infty,0) \cup (1,\infty) \to \mathbb{R},$ $$f(x)=\begin{cases} x, \text{when $x\leqslant0$} \\ \frac{1}{x-1}, \text{when $x>1$} \end{cases}$$ Determine if $f$ is continuous? Also determine if $f^{-1} : \mathbb{R} \to (-\infty,0) \cup (1,\infty)$ is continuous.

The problem for continuity with $f$ occurs at $x=1$ and doesn't seem to be continuous when approaching from the positive axis. For the inverse of $f$ I got that $$f^{-1}(x) = \begin{cases} x, \text{when $x\leqslant0$} \\ \frac{x+1}{x}, \text{when $x>1$} \end{cases} $$

for which when approaching $x=1$ from the negative $x$-axis evaluates to $1$ and from the positive axis it evaluates to $2$. So also the inverse also isn't continuous?

Answer (score 1):

There is *no problem whatsoever* at $1$, since $1$ does not belong to the domain of $f$.

And you got the inverse wrong. Remember that the domain of $f^{-1}$ is the range of $f$, which is $\Bbb R$. Actually, we have$$f^{-1}(x)=\begin{cases}x&\text{ if }x\leqslant0\\1+\frac1x&\text{ if }x>0,\end{cases}$$which is discontinuous at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$1$ is not in the domain  and so continuity at $1$ does not arise.  $f$ is  continuous  but the inverse function is not continuous at $0$.